# Access SQL - Show Additional Columns in Count Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to get detailed list of duplicates, the `Foldername` is the duplicate value.
I need count of duplicates instances AND other corresponding columns such as `FullPath` for each instance of a duplicate.

I'm trying to return a list of every single fullpath with it's corresponding foldername count, as well as additional columns such as unit, size and so forth.

```
FolderName (has the possibility of a duplicate)
FullPath (is completly unique)
```

I've give a few stabs at this; in SQL Server this seems more apparent... but in Access I'm a bit lost here.

This is the basic SQL I've come up with so far:

```
    /* ''''''''''''''Works but doesn't return Count'''''''''''''' */
Select Snapshot.Unit, Snapshot.FolderName, Snapshot.FullPath
From Snapshot
Where Snapshot.FolderName in 
(
    Select Snapshot.FolderName
    From Snapshot
    Group by Snapshot.Foldername
    Having Count(Snapshot.FolderName)> 1
)
Order by Snapshot.FolderName, Snapshot.FullPath
```

Here's an example output that I'd like to get:

```
Unit       FolderName     FullPath                          Count
BCU        Misc           C:\blah\blah\blah\Misc            2
ENV        Misc           R:\blah\blah\blah\Misc            2
CLR        Monkey         Q:\blah\blah\blah\blah\Monkey     17
ATL        Zebra          Z:\blah\blah\zoo\Zebra            24
```

I referenced: 
[Having trouble using count() in Access SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507392/having-trouble-using-count-in-access-sql-query)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the counting in your subquery and `INNER JOIN` Snapshot to the subquery.

```
SELECT s.Unit, s.FolderName, s.FullPath, sub.num_dupes
FROM
    Snapshot AS s
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT FolderName, Count(*) AS num_dupes
        FROM Snapshot
        GROUP BY FolderName
        HAVING Count(*)> 1
    ) AS sub
    ON s.FolderName = sub.FolderName
ORDER BY s.FolderName, s.FullPath
```

Comment: Bingo! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks I believed you've helped me before. Thanks again.

Comment: Any recommendations on books or websites on how to better learn subqueries and more complex queries?

Comment: Check these 2 pages by Allen Browne: http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html and http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-02.html

Comment: Thanks Hans! Nice article appreciate it.